# onDragEnter/onDragLeave on antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd, drag

I have a problem with the onDragEnter/onDragLeave events in react on an antd table.

For information, I use antd and react 18.

```
     /**
       * 
       * @param e 
       */
      function handleDragEnter(e: DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
        console.log('e:', e)
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        setDragged(true)
      }
    
    
      /**
       * 
       * @param e 
       */
      function handleDragLeave(e: DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
        console.log('e:', e)
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        setDragged(false)
      }

    return (
      <>
        <div className="DrivesList" onDrop={handleDrop} onDragEnter={handleDragEnter} onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}>
          <Table
            className={classNames({
              'DrivesList-table-loading': droppedFilesLoading,
            })}

....
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, events are triggered many times when I drag over the board :

[image: console when I drag the hover table]

For information, if I comment the table (still the main div), these events work perfectly.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

PS:I want to add a border around the div when I drag over it.

Comment: As far as I know, the antd table takes a lot of re-render for any action.
You can test this by simply adding console.log to the table element and hovering over the table.

You will see the same result as now, but with your logs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, my component is re-rendered several times... I don't see how this can be solved.

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33637

Look at this string: "This bug occur, BUT it's fixed if we use shouldCellUpdate: () => false, at the column."

Comment: Thanks, I've added this property for each of my columns but it doesn't change anything... As soon as I change cell I have: onDragEnter/OnDragLeave which are triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using pointer-events: none in child.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to your children inside a `<div ...> ... </div>` where you hanle *onDragEnter* and *onDragLeave*.
[run in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stackoverflow-com-questions-77357399-85frfk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)